# Multiple video from one personal video using cdn links for video js

Tags: video, video-streaming, video.js

Can anyone show me some way of creating multiple videos for my one personal videos i.e original_video,original_video_720,original_video_420 etc. I was using wowza streaming engine(trial version) for this purpose but i have gone through all the video tutorial of wowza but it doesn't provide multiple copies from single video files.I want to make multiple copies of video and selecting the videos according to Adaptive bitrate(ABR). I have checked the video link in video js started with cdn like 
https://cdn.theoplayer.com/video/star_wars_episode_vii-the_force_awakens_official_comic-con_2015_reel_(2015)/index.m3u8.
Can anyone help me how to create this link for my video on theoplayer(trial version)? I will purchase this once i will use one demo video. Recommend me any streaming engine for this purpose. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: this is the demo of what i want mine videos with video-js.https://halibegic.github.io/hls/. Any one help me with this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i m able to find the answer that software like ffmpeg would be well suited to create different videos of format like 360p,420p,720p etc. Some really good tutorial to go through how to use ffmpeg commands for the purpose.

```
https://docs.peer5.com/guides/production-ready-hls-vod/.
```

I have used the following pastebin for my question.

```
 https://pastebin.com/raw/jctc0MJ7
```

This might be helpful for some one who uses the video-js for web application.